# How do I update this defun to select region

Tags: region, defun

I wrote this function which takes a string and writes out self.var for each entry in the string. This helps me create python classes faster.

```
(defun elf-python-self (str)
  "Parse the arguemnts in STR and write out self.var = var."
  (interactive (list (read-string "Argument List: ")))
  (message str)
  (let ((var-list (split-string str ","))
        (var-name))
    (forward-line)
    (move-beginning-of-line nil)
    (while (> (length var-list) 0)
      (setq var-name (strip (pop var-list)))
      (message var-name)
      (insert (format "        self.%s = %s\n" var-name var-name)))))
```

If I type `a, b, c` then I get the following

```
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
```

How do I modify this function to apply the code to the selected region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this which describes the interactive region https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605846/how-do-i-access-the-contents-of-the-current-region-in-emacs-lisp and applied it to my function below using buffer-substring to extract the string from the region.

```
(defun elf-python-self-region (start end)
  "Split the region START to END based on comma and strings write out self.var = var."
  (interactive "r")
  (elf-python-self (buffer-substring start end)))
```